# Is there a way to show specific items from RSS feed in Power apps?

Tags: xml, rss, powerapps

I have a RSS feed with some categories. The list is long, so in `Power Apps`, I would like to only show certain items that have category = "X" instead of showing the whole list.

`RSS.ListFeedItems("URL HERE")` works for all items, but how can I show a part or a targeted list? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never worked with RSS, but let’s say you have a feed with a field of Categories:

```
Filter(
  RSS.listFeedItems( YourUrl ),
  “YourCategoryAsText” in Categories
)
```

Maybe this gets you started?

Edit: small change

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot! Do you happen to know how a table can be checked when the output is [object[ [object]?

Comment: If the return looks like array, where each item of item name has several objects you can use YourArray.InnerObject.InnerObject.  This will return an array of the inner inner object which can be used in a gallery for example. You can use first( YourArray.InnerObject.InnerObject ).YourDesiredField to retrieve the first value of the property of the innerinnerobject. Lots of inners, but this will get you started with the basics :)

Comment: Same for [table]? I mean, it's basically a table in a table...